How do switch mode power supplies solve the half energy loss problem in the charging of a capacitor?
If we charge a capacitor C with a DC source of voltage V, the energy stored in the capacitor is ½CV² and the energy wasted in wires is also ½CV².
Many videos say that SMPS minimizes this cleverly by switching fast and thus not allowing the capacitor to fully discharge.
I don't get how the energy is not wasted in fast switching.
The energy wasted in one long slow cycle is high in slow switching (50 Hz), but in fast switching, say 50 kHz, small amounts of energy is still wasted a thousand times more in one second. What am I missing?
Apologies for the analogy, but giving me $1k one time is same as giving me a penny 100k times. I'm not seeing how fast switching minimizes the capacitor charging/discharging energy loss issue.

" the energy wasted in wires is 1/2CV^2." - Why? Please update your question with a justification of this statement.  In the situation you describe, the energy wasted in wires is simply resistive heating, calculated with Ohm's Law.  With adequate wire size, this can be a fraction of one watt.  For example, 10 A through 6" of #16 wire causes a heating loss of 0.2 W.

@AnalogKid When charging a capacitor from 0V through a resistor the energy dissipated in the resistor is equal to the energy stored in the capacitor, leading to 50% loss. This is true regardless of the magnitude of the resistance.

Your premise seems wrong. "Many videos say that SMPS minimizes this cleverly by switching fast and thus not allowing the capacitor to fully discharge." What videos? "The energy wasted in one long slow cycle is high in slow switching(50Hz,) but in fast switching, say 50kHz, small amounts of energy is still wasted a thousand times more in one second." This needs context to be making that claim.

This is highly relevant as it explains capacitor charging efficiency without any inductors: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/681739/254097

There are some dangerous answers here either reasonably wrong or with unclear assertions. || In a circuit with capacitance and resistance and no inductance then the 50% loss you are seeing is a consequence of the maximum power transfer theorum. Switching rapidly does not address this issue. This loss can be reduced by charging capacitors by a very small percentage of their current voltage. To cover a wide voltage range doing this requires multiple stages and some systems for specialist uses have done this.

By putting an inductor in series with your input and output capacitor. On a real SMPS, a lot more than that but for any efficient one, some inductor is in the current path.
Please simulate or hand-calculate your capacitor to capacitor energy transfer with an inductor in series and see what happens.
Your initial example is also a bit flawed since you could ramp up the voltage. But I assume you are referring to the classic school example of connecting a charged capacitor to a non charged one, where you will experience 50+ % losses.
Here is the school experiment, 1 F capacitors, first one charged to 1 V, second one to 0 V. 1 ohm of resistance between them. The students can try to change the R (from ESR, wire or resistor) as much as they want, the end result is the same, only the time scale changes.

Here is the same with the resistor changed to an inductor:

Practically all the energy has been transferred from input capacitor to output. The problem which comes is that at this point, you need to stop the transfer with some switch, preferably semiconductor, or you will just have a resonant circuit which will ring until parasitic effects brings everything to a nice Vin=Vout=0.5 V equilibrium, just as in the example above.

Sure, if you try to charge a cap all at once (step dV/dt) you will have a big IR drop in the wire. A perfect capacitor would present zero impedance to a step waveform, so the theoretically infinite current will find some impedance somwhere, be it the power source or in the connections.
But what if we feed the cap with some slew-limited waveform, like a sine or a ramp, then interrupt the current at just the right time? All the energy makes it in. The controlled dV/dt makes the resistive losses smaller.
As it is, the output (bulk) capacitor in a SMPS serves only to smooth out the output. Its voltage doesn’t swing very much, just the ripple of tens to hundreds of mV. It's the nature of that ripple that limits loss: it's a sawtooth which has limited dV/dt.
In switchers it’s all about the inductor. It’s the primary energy storage and transfer mechanism. Inductors store energy as flux, the magnetic field that builds up around its conductors when current is passed through it. By alternating between increasing and decreasing the flux, we can transfer energy between different voltage domains with only small losses.
Simple SMPS operation has two phases. Consider a 'buck' converter like this one (simulate it here):

Observe what happens as the switch toggles between power and ground.

inductor 'charge' (switch to Vdd)

Current flows from Vdd through the inductor in an increasing ramp.  As the current builds the flux increases, storing energy. Main current flow is from input power, through the switch, the inductor, then into the bulk cap and load, returning back to the source.

inductor 'discharge' (switch to GND)

Current flows from GND through the inductor as a decreasing ramp. The inductor flux collapses, releasing energy by dumping its current into the load and bulk capacitor. Current flows from the inductor, through the load and output cap, to GND, to low-side switch, then finally back to the inductor.
With perfect components (switches, inductor, capacitor), in theory there will be a 100% power transfer. However, every component has some resistance and will shed some heat. The bulk of the loss is typically in the inductor, followed by he switches. Still, efficiencies in the 90% and higher range are not unheard of.
Switching power supply designers seek to use the lowest resistance inductor possible for a given cost and space allowance. Higher switching frequency allows lower inductance values, so the inductor can have fewer turns of bigger diameter wire, and thus have lower resistance. Or, the inductor can be physically smaller, even small enough to be integrated as part of the chip package.
The trade-off with faster switching is that parasitic losses are higher. Still, the smaller, lower resistance inductor is worth it: 1MHz or higher switching is widely used today for very compact designs.
But what if the inductor were a superconductor. Its resistive losses will be near zero. In fact, it's possible to 'charge' a superconducting inductor with current, then connect it back to itself so the current will circulate forever. That's how MRI magnets work: they're chilled to nearly absolute zero with liquid helium, then loaded up with current to make the required flux. Far too exotic for an SMPS, but you get the idea.

Below is an LTspice simulation showing charging a capacitor through an inductor with ideal components.
Note that the capacitor voltage (yellow trace) reaches twice the source voltage (green trace) at the end of the charge.
During the charge the inductor current (purple trace) reaches its peak at half the charge time where it has inductively stored half the charge energy (instead of it being dissipated in a resistor) and then transfers it to the capacitor at which point the inductor current drops to zero.
Thus the energy (2 Joules) delivered by the source (red trace, small left window) equals the energy delivered to (and stored by) the capacitor (blue trace, small right window), so there is no loss during the charging.


…and presumably (as noted at the end of winny's answer), if you kept the simulation going with no switch to break the circuit, the current through the inductor would reverse and the capacitor would discharge back down to 0V and then the whole process would repeat.

If a capacitor were to be charged via some resistance, in a typical RC arrangement, the voltage across the resistor will change between some maximum and some minimum, and during that transition it will have a non-zero voltage across it, and a non-zero current. Consequently, it receives energy at a rate \$I \times V\$, energy which the resistor "discards" as heat. That energy is lost, and cannot be recovered. This is the cause of the 50% efficiency problem.
The difference with an SMPS is that it does not employ resistance (at least, not intentionally) as part of the charging system. Rather, it uses an inductance, which doesn't just throw away energy delivered to it by \$I \times V\$ power. It stores that energy in a magnetic field, energy which can be recovered later by the capacitor.
Thus energy in an SMPS isn't discarded, as a resistor would discard it. A better description would be "exchanged". There is a regular exchange of energy, between input voltage source, inductor and output capacitor. There is (ideally) no resistance in any of the current paths, which would result in energy being lost as heat, and so an ideal SMPS can be 100% energy efficient.

The goal, then, for any SMPS design is to aim for zero resistance everywhere. That's impossible. For instance, if you employ a diode (as many SMPSs do), then there will be a non-zero voltage across that diode, while it passes current, and power will dissipated there, resulting in heating, lost energy.
The switching element is usually a MOSFET. Ideally, you would like that transistor to have either infinite resistance (\$P=\frac{V^2}{R}=0\$), or zero resistance (\$P=I^2R=0\$), so that no power is ever dissipated there. Sadly, the transistor takes time to transition between those two states, and there will therefore be an interval during which its resistance is finite and non-zero, and it is conducting current. During that interval, then, the transistor will dispense with some energy as heat.
To mitigate this, the designer aims to have transistors transition as quickly as possible between on and off states, to minimise the time they spend dissipating power as heat.
From the perspective of the switching element, making more transitions-per-second is clearly going to dissipate more power in the switch than fewer. In this sense, lower switching frequency (distinct from transition time) is more efficient.
Where the inductor is concerned, though, exchanging smaller energy "packets" more frequently is preferred over larger packets less frequently. This helps the inductor avoid core saturation, permitting the use of smaller inductors, with lighter, less "lossy" cores.
Switching frequency is a compromise. Too low, and the inductor can saturate, becoming a resistance. Too high and the transistor spends more time being a resistor. As I explained before, the goal is to eliminate resistance wherever one can, since resistances are the only places in any electrical system where energy can be lost as heat.

The voltage across an ideal inductor can switch polarity instantaneously without any loss of energy.  In a continuous-mode buck mode converter, if the supply voltage is 15 volts and the load is at 5 volts and drawing 1 amp, then the coil will have about 1 amp flowing through it continuously; the current will ripple up and down slightly, but it will stay around an amp in any case.  During 1/3 of each switching cycle the coil will be in series between the supply and the load, with 10 volts across it, and the remaining 2/3 of the time the coil will sit directly across the load with the load's 5 volts across it.  Since the average voltage across the coil will be (1/3)(10) + (2/3)(-5), i.e. zero, the current on each cycle will be the same as the one before.
The coil will take current from the supply 1/3 of the time, but transfer current to the load all the time, and neither scenario requires any voltage drop anywhere other than in the coil.
Real coils aren't ideal inductors, of course, and the fact that the switching frequency will be slow enough allow the current in the coil to increase and decrease means this model isn't perfect, but treating the coil as a device which will pass a constant amount of current provided the average voltage across it is zero is a useful model for analyzing equilibrium behavior.

Fast switching to reduce switching losses and how to charge a capacitor with low percentage of losses are two totally different technical ideas. Fast switching is useful in a circuit which charges a capacitor, but something else is also needed to keep the losses low.
You can have even a resistive load and fast switching reduces losses in the switch, because a fast switch turns on and off rapidly. The period, when only a part of the switched voltage is over the load and the rest is over the switch and causes there dissipation (P=UI, as you may remember) is short. If one changes a slow type transistor to a switching circuit which should have a fast one, the dissipation in the transistor can grow too high and the transistor can be killed by overheating.
Switching power supplies charge their output capacitors with pulses, as you seemingly already know. And that charged voltage feeds the load which is connected to the power supply. To keep the voltage stable within few millivolts new charging pulses are usually injected at least tens of thousands per a second.
As you have reasoned, having fast switches is not enough to make the losses low when capacitors are charged. Fast switches are needed, but that's not the fundamental idea which makes the losses low just during the charging of the capacitors. The actual trick is that the switch does not charge the output capacitor from a DC voltage. The switch connects an inductor to the unstabilized DC voltage. The current of the inductor starts to grow gradually. Hopefully you know the induction law. It states that the inductor current growth rate (amperes per a second) has formula di/dt = U/L, where L is the inductance and U is the voltage between the ends of the inductor.
When the inductor current has grown high enough the switch is suddenly turned OFF. The inductor current doesn't halt. It goes on by generating so high voltage that a way for the current is found - a wanted one or through the insulation. In power supplies there's no sparks nor smoke. The circuit has a diode or another switching transistor which allows the inductor current to go on as a charging pulse to the output capacitor. We say that the magnetic energy of the inductor is loaded to the capacitor. That happens with minimal losses if the inductor, output capacitor and the diode or switching transistor and in many cases also the transformer in the same circuit have all low resistances.
There are several variations of the idea to optimize the costs in different cases. For example in flyback type power supplies the transformer is at the same time the mentioned inductor and a transformer which steps the voltage voltage up or down.
To produce the wanted output voltage with different loads and with varying input voltages switching power supplies have tricky control circuits which regulate how often and how high currents are let to get built through the inductors and then released to charge the output capacitor. SMPS engineering is far from trivial, but the makers of controller ICs have published good application notes. They are no substitute for understanding the principles. Understanding makes possible to utilize the application notes.

It doesn't -- you still have to charge and discharge the gate capacitance (gate driver losses) and the switch node capacitances (FET losses).  The output capacitor, however, you can consider as charged with a current as opposed to "slammed" on like how you might imagine charging a capacitor with a voltage source is, and this doesn't have the given "half the energy is lost" phenomenon.
SPICE simulators can simulate this well. Play around with charging w/ Voltage source and resistor as opposed to current source.
